# Program to help sort files

Tags: windows, sorting

I'm going through a lot of computers and a lot of data here and there.
I'm moving it all to a server so everybody has access to it.

There i have a folder for each computer. But a lot of the data is the same.

Is there any program to help me combine the data that is the same ?
It hell trying to do this manually.

Basically i want to tell this program, hey check this folder here C:/test and if there are any files that are duplicated, delete one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a tool for manual comparison of large directory structures, try [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/).
If you want automatic comparison scripts, [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) diff is good, possibly embedded in a shell script.